# Имя файла в стримах. new File

Tags: java

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File(r.readLine()));
FileReader reader = new FileReader(r.readLine());
```

Есть ли разница между объявлениями имен для стримов и что нам дает new File().Или же он сам прописывается , если не написали ?

Answer (score 5):

Разницы нет, т.к. если посмотреть на коструктор, где передается строка, то увидим следующее:

```
public FileReader(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    super(new FileInputStream(fileName));
}

public FileInputStream(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this(name != null ? new File(name) : null);
}
```

А вот коструктор, где файл

```
public FileReader(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    super(new FileInputStream(file));
}
```

Как видим, в обоих случаях вызывается один и тот же конструктор у FileInputStream

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему (например, если `r` у вас является экземпляром `BufferedReader`), это разные [конструкторы](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html#constructor_summary): в первом случае это конструктор

```
FileReader(File file)
```

а во втором

```
FileReader(String fileName)
```

В обоих случаях создаётся новый `FileReader`, но в первом конструкторе в качестве параметра указывается файл `File`, а во втором указывается имя файла как строка.